# Python writing to file failure

Tags: python, function, for-loop, parameters, console.writeline

I am having a bit of a difficulty with writing to file. The setup is that I have some data in one file. It has some integers, single words, sentences (like addresses and such), decimals and other (for example dates). I want to divide the data into several categories and have each category written into a separate file. This is what I managed so far:

```
def data_reading():
    #document_reading.close() = open("lines.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
    document_writing_integers = open("integers.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    #document_writing_others = open("decimals.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    document_writing_letters = open("words.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    #document_writing_sentences = open("sentences.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    data = []
    integers = []
    letters = []
    sentences = []
    others = []
    with open("lines.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        for row in file:
            row = row.strip().replace("\n", "")
            data.extend(row.split(","))
        for value in data:
            if value.isnumeric():
                #print(value + " - integer")
                integers.append(value)
                document_writing_integers.write(value + "\n")
            elif value.isalpha():
                letters.append(value.upper())
                document_writing_letters.write(value + "\n")
                #print(value + " - alphabetical strings")
            elif value.endswith("."):
                sentences.append(value.lower().capitalize())
                #print(value + " - sentence")
                #document_writing_sentences.write(value + "\n")
            elif value.count(".") == 1:
                others.append(value)
                #document_writing_others.write(value + "\n")
                #print(value + " - float")
            else:
                print("None of the above '" + value + "'.")
                break
    #document_reading.close()
    document_writing_integers.close()
    #document_writing_others.close()
    document_writing_letters.close()
    #document_writing_sentences.close()       
    return integers, letters, sentences, others

def sentence_writing(full_sentences):
    document_writing_sentences = open("sentences.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    textline = sentences
    for items in textline:
        document_writing_sentences.write(items + "\n")
    document_writing_sentences.close()
    return textline

def writing_others(last):
    document_writing_others = open("decimals.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    decimals = others
    for rows in decimals:
        document_writing_sentences.write(rows + "\n")
    document_writing_others.close()
    return decimals

def the_main():
    integers, letters, sentences, others = data_reading()
    #textline = sentence_writing(sentences)
    #decimals = writing_others(last)

the_main()

#integers, letters, sentences, others = data_reading()
#print(integers)
#print(sentences)
#print(letters)
#print(others)
```

I am failing to write to files. The output from data_reading() looks ok, I looked it up with print(). So integers are for instance [12, 23923, 1, etc], the decimals [1.3 67.1], the sentences contain [Address unknown for example] and others are dates for example, 22.04.78. The decimals and sentences are not writing to files at all and the words are not in all capitals, for some reason. The main issue is that there is something wrong with my sentences and other file writing functions, and I am not good enough to spot the cause. Any feedback is appreciated.

Edited: My post was a bit verbose and overwhelming. I think I narrowed the problem down, or at leas I hope so. If I look just at my write-to-file function:

```
def sentence_writing(full_sentences):
    document_writing_sentences = open("virke.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    textline = modified_sentences
    #while True:
    print(textline)
    for items in textline:
        document_writing_sentences.write(items + "\n")
    document_writing_sentences.close()
    return textline
```

From print() I get ['Sunday service.', 'Adriano chilentano.', 'I buy american.'] - as I wanted, first letter capitalized, the rest are small. So I guess I would be interested in knowing the best way to write that to a file. I was getting no luck with the normal way I was doing it, the while loop.

Comment: Can  you edit to clean up the indentation, commented lines, etc. ? Also the mixing of with open and just plain open is not good practice, the former is preferred.

Comment: @paisanco, absolutely. Thanks for input. I didn't read about open/with open until today and I was halfway though with the function. Thought Id give it a go anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The the code was not working because of the bad parameters in my writing to file functions. The working solution would be:

```
def data_reading():
    data = []
    integers = []
    letters = []
    sentences = []
    others = []
    with open("data_file.txt") as file:
        for row in file:
            row = row.strip().replace("\n", "")
            data.extend(row.split(","))
        for value in data:
            if value.isnumeric():
                integers.append(value)
            elif value.isalpha():
                letters.append(value.upper())
            elif value.endswith("."):
                sentences.append(value.lower().capitalize())
            elif value.count(".") == 1:
                others.append(value)
            else:
                print("Data not recognized '" + value + "'.")
            break
    return integers, letters, sentences, others

def sentence_writing(full_sentences):
    document_writing_sentences = open("complete_sentences.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    textline = full_sentences
    for items in textline:
        if items == "0":
            break
        else:
            document_writing_sentences.write(items + "\n")
    document_writing_sentences.close()
    return None

def writing_others(last):
    document_writing_others = open("decimals_file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    decimals = last
    for items in decimals:
        if items == "0":
            break
        else:
            document_writing_others.write(items + "\n")
    document_writing_others.close()
    return None

def writing_words(single_word):
    document_writing_letters = open("solitary_words.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    words = single_word
    for items in words:
        if items == "0":
            break
        else:
            document_writing_letters.write(items + "\n")
    document_writing_letters.close()
    return None

def writing_integers(integers):
    document_writing_integers = open("integers_extracted.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    for items in integers:
        if items == "0":
            break
        else:
            document_writing_integers.write(items + "\n")
    document_writing_integers.close()
    return None

def main():
    integers, letters, sentences, others = data_reading()
    writing_integers(integers)
    single_word = letters
    writing_words(single_word)
    last = others
    writing_others(last)
    full_sentences = sentences
    sentence_writing(full_sentences)
    return None

main()
```